# Firebase log says Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value￼

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

This is the function that returns the error. I am not good with javascript, and I've tried tinkering with the return but nothing seems to work.

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
  .document('school/counts')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();

  const admin_notices = newValue.admin_notices;

  if (admin_notices === 14){
    admin.firestore().collection('notifications').orderBy("date",'desc').limit(1).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        return doc.ref.delete();
      });

      return;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return;    
    });
  }    
});
```

(Edit) In case the intention isn't clear. I just want to remove the last notification if the number of notifications exceeds 14.

Comment: It probably goes into one of the `return;` parts. If you assign the result of this function to a variable, that variable will be undefined (because you return nothing)

Comment: Also, a return inside a `forEach` doesn't seem right.

Comment: I just want to remove the last document. Where should I put the return?

Comment: You need to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  You're doing a lot of that in this function, but you're ignoring the promise chain started by `get()`.  Also, the `return doc.ref.delete()` actually isn't helping your situation because you're just returning a promise from an inner function, not the outer function.

Comment: You definitely need to understand how to work effectively with JavaScript promises in order to write code for Cloud Functions.  It might be easier to learn this without the complications added by Cloud Functions itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson then how do i return a promise from the outer function? Can you write the code? I am very new to this

Comment: Check out [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that demonstrate using a promise correctly. You need to `return` your whole `admin.firestore().colle...`, and also nix the `return` inside the `forEach` loop.